# Are humans suppose to succeed gods in Far East mythologies?

Tags: japanese, chinese, korean

Although this question is mostly inspired by video games, I'm searching for the cultural (mythological?) root of this "trope" (I lack a better term).

At this point, I encountered it multiple times to see a pattern. If you're unaware then let me explain that there's a common cliche regarding Japanese Role Playing games: "Use The Power Of Friendship To Kill God" ;-) But while I've been playing games like **Xenoblade Chronicles**, **Fire Emblem Echoes: Shadows of Valentia** or **Final Fantasy XII** I noticed that it kind of evolved from simply killing someone powerful, to **succeeding him and inheriting his world, or even replacing them**. From the reoccurring quote "History in the hands of man" in FFXII, or deciding whether the world belongs to a god figure or the human characters like in Xenoblade Chronicles game. There's a lot of talk about free will and the fact that the choice belongs to humans and so on.

Does this way of thinking correspond with Far East Asian cultures? Does it have roots in myths and legends or is it rather a contemporary thing?

Comment: Maybe only after death? In classical Bhuddism there are six realms of rebirth, including the possibility of being reborn as a god. However the whole goal is to break the rebirth cycle and reach nirvana.